# function call error after closing a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

This is my first question so sorry if I'm not being clear in less words.
I'm writing a python script in which i ask user to input operation he wants to perform. I've two functions with to specific operations (A and N). 
I've used if-else statement to check and apply specific function and write whole output to a new file. after closing file handle i'm calling another function in same check box (if-else). **about()** its output should be displayed on command prompt according to if-else check but i get

```
    "Value error: I/O operation on closed file."
```

this is what i've done so far

```
    obj = PhysioCal()
if (args.operation == 'N' or args.operation == 'n'):
    with open (args.output,"w") as fout:
        sys.stdout=fout
        t_n=obj.nucleotide(obj.fasta_reader(args.input))
        sys.stdout.close()
    obj.about(t_n)
elif (args.operation == 'A' or args.operation == 'a'):
    with open (args.output,"w") as fout:
        sys.stdout=fout
        t_a=obj.amino_acid(obj.fasta_reader(args.input))
        sys.stdout.close()
    obj.about(t_a)
else:
    obj.about(0)
    print("\n\t\t\tProcess Failed")
    print("\t\t\aYou have seleccted wrong operation")
    print("\t\tuse -h argument for help menu")
```

here **t_n** and **t_a** are time which functions return.
about function shows that time on command prompt.

also is that write way to get all the outputs of function in a file instead of prints on cmd ?

Comment: Why are you overwriting `sys.stdout` and what do you think `sys.stdout.close()` is doing? Hint: you don't need to do any of those since you are using `with open`

Comment: Does `obj.nucleotide` implicitly use standard output? Otherwise, it's not clear how `fout` gets used at all.

Comment: my functions use `print` statements. so i was searching for a way to redirect all those **print** statements to a file i wanted to write. found this way somewhere i don't remember now. couldn't find any other way. @DeepSpace

Comment: @UmerFarooq Google how to write to files in Python. You don't need to redirect anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you `reasigned sys.stdout` to `fout` and then closed it the program can no longer print to stdout. You can use fout directly without the reassignment to write to it. Check the python documentation for writing to files.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is either overlooking how to pass `fout` as an argument to the various `obj` methods, or he needs to mock `sys.stdout` to make those methods use `fout` instead.

Comment: Without know the about methods implementation we can only assume. But OP did say the about function shows the time on the command prompt, which I assume is to print the value of `t_a` to stdout.  Since stdout is closed at that point in time the error is being thrown.

Comment: so i think i need to change the way i'm redirecting all my print statements to a file.